# jQuery datepicker set position

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am setting the 'month' position dynamically on an inline jquery datepicker widget. The problem is, once I have set a position it will not let me select dates prior to this. Is there another way of doing this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LLcHh/21/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inline').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showCurrentAtPos:-4,
        minDate: +1
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by => once I have set a position it will not let me select dates prior to this. I dont understand

Comment: @PratikJoshi If it is set (onload) to position 'June' then the top arrow keys will not allow me to navigate to a month prior to 'June'

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `mindate : +1`, which means it begins from tomorrow, the current month cannot be less than the first one in the row. So the second option is not applicable.

Here's a fiddle of how it works without it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLcHh/22/)

As you can see there is no problem with selecting dates. 
I'm not sure yet, but I think the current position cannot be less than 0 in this situation.
The documentation does not say anything specific about this, But is this position important to you ?

**EDIT:**

I had an idea, you can set the date afterwards to go 4 months in the future.

here's an updated fiddle : [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLcHh/24/)

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I need to set the position unfortunately.

Comment: then the minDate is definitely stopping that. It's either one or the other

Comment: Yeah. With this widget i agree unless you want to throw some kind of message if a previous date is chosen which doesn't seem too user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

```
minDate: +1
```

Remove the minDate. This is restricting prior dates

Done the research. had to override the default behaviour of datepicker in atleast 3 functions

http://jsfiddle.net/c95AV/4/

Comment: But I need todays date as the minimum selected

Answer (score 0):

Your min date is stopping you from going back. I also don't believe showCurrentAtPos should have a negative value - it should be used to set which calendar pane the current date is in, not which month starts first.

To set the date, use the set date function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inline').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showCurrentAtPos:1
    }).datepicker("setDate","+1d");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottysmalls/c95AV/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need the current position at -4